# Merge 2 dataframe on index with different timestamp in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, merge, timestamp

I have 2 dataframes with different timestamps and different lengths.

First Dataframe,`df`, has 1054 rows and looks like this:

[image: First Dataframe]

Second Dataframe,`df_temp`, has 2629 rows and looks like this:

[image: Second Dataframe]

I have no clue where to begin. The time stamp is almost close and I know how to merge dataframes with similar index but not this one. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

`df_merged=pd.concat([df,df_temp]).sort_index()`

I tried this before as well. When I add these together the index is kind of sorted but it gives me NaN values for where the data is missing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
pd.concat([df,df_temp]).sort_index()
```

or

```
pd.concat([df,df_temp.rename(columns=dict(zip(df_temp.columns,df.columns)))]).sort_index()
```

Comment: I tried this before as well. When I add these together the index is kind of sorted but it gives me NaN values for where the data is missing.

Comment: What is your expected dataframe ?

Comment: Actually I found a solution to this by using `df_merged=df_merged.fillna(method='ffill')`
But thank you for your help.